# Can’t install 64 bit linux distros on A1176 2006 Mac Mini?

Tags: mac, unix, 32-bit, 64-bit

I am trying to install a linux distribution called Ubuntu MATE onto a 2006 Mac Mini. I can’t get 64 bit install media to boot but I can with 32 bit. The Core 2 Duo in the computer is a 64 bit CPU so it should work, how can I fix this?

Comment: https://lowendmac.com/2006/mac-mini-late-2006/ these articles contradict that 2006 models had a 64-bit CPU. It was introduced in the 2007 model https://lowendmac.com/2007/mac-mini-mid-2007/

Comment: Anyway, this is basically a Linux question, you might get better answers on an Ubuntu-focused site. We can migrate it for you if you want.

Comment: Zach: The model A1176 is either a 32 bit 2006 mac mini or 64 bit 2007 mac mini. Apple never made a 64 bit 2006 mac mini. So please determine what Mac you actually have and correct your question. Also, what was the installation media? A DVD, flash drive or something else? If a flash drive, then how did you create the flash drive installer?

Comment: @DavidAnderson You‘re right, I misread T2300 :-)